# A function of $f\circ g$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functions

This is studying for my midterm.

Let $f(x)=x^2/(x+1)$ and $g(x)=2x-3$ A function of $f\circ g$ is:

So I begin with the equation:

$$x^2/(x+1) \cdot 2x-3$$

Add one to the denominator of the second equation.

$$x^2/(x+1)\cdot(2x-3)/1$$

Multiplying i get:

$$(2x^2-3x^2)/(x+1)$$

Although this isn't right. Could somebody help me out?

Comment: Should it be $f$ in both places or is one $F$ and the other $f$? Also, is it $f\cdot g$ or $f\circ g$?

Comment: It is completely unclear what you're trying to achieve here, **and** what it is you're doing to achieve it.

Comment: Apologies, it's not supposed to be a capital f.

Comment: As Michael pointed out, is it supposed to be f of g? (function of a function)

Comment: Oh, Michael, it's the second, f o g I'm not sure how to format it.

Comment: You shouldn't write $x^2/(x+1)\cdot 2x-3$ if you mean $x^2/(x+1)\cdot(2x-3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x+1}$ and $g(x)=2x-3$. So $f(g)= \frac{(2x-3)^2}{(2x-3)+1}=\frac{(2x-3)^2}{2x-2}$.

Answer (score 0):

By the definition,

$$(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x)) = f(2x-3) = \dots$$

I expect you can finish this yourself, but in case you still don't know what's next...

> $\displaystyle\ldots = \frac{(2x-3)^2}{(2x-3)+1}.$